# Recursive .equals method from call to super.equals

Tags: java, equals

**Edit**

I did a very poor job and gave incomplete information for anyone to determine the cause of my issue. The real issue was that I had a nested class in Animal which had its own .equals which called .equals on its outer type. (So calling .equals on animal called .equals on animal from the nested class's .equals).

---

I have three classes in an inheritance tree. Let's say they're `Animal` --> `Dog<Owner>` --> `DogWithHumanOwner`.

So DogWithHumanOwner is an implementation of the generic Dog that specifically has a Human for its owner.

I have overriden Animal's and Dog's .equal methods. Dog's .equal method looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!super.equals(obj))
        return false;

    [other stuff]

    return true;
}
```

What I'm actually using though is a DogWithHumanOwner. It seems that when I try to compare the equality of two DogWithHumanOwner, the dogWithHumanOwnerinherits the equals method from `Dog<Owner>`, which calls super.equals, which is the dogWithHumanOwner's super classes' .equals method, which is the method it's in, and so it causes a recursive loop and a stackoverflow.

(I don't need to compare any specific properties of the implementations of the `Dog<Owner>` class, because I do that in `Dog<Owner>` and owners need to have proper equals methods.)

What is the best practice for writing a .equals method that avoid this issue? I'm drawing a blank. Should I just manually test the equality without calling super at all?

Edit: I had to remove the BlackLabs, because it didn't make sense why I would want to do this with blackLabs.

Comment: Superclass of `Dog` should be `Animal`. Calling its `equals` function should not lead to recursion.

Comment: @Madbreaks - Note that `BlackLab.equals` has **not** been overridden so it defaults to `Dog.equals` which is `super.equals` which is therefore `Dog.equals` because `BlackLab.super` is `Dog`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon A call to `super.equals` in `Dog` will always resolve to `Animal.equals` (it doesn't change based on the runtime type).

Comment: Er, anyone know what the escape character is for <? My generic carrots are being hidden!

Comment: @CorayThan Use inline code formatting with the \` character, for example \`Dog<Owner>\` formats to `Dog<Owner>`. You can also use &lt; and &gt; for < and >.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood `super`.
`super.x()` is always a call to the super class of the class **calling** it.

The class calling `super.equals()` in your case is `Dog` and not `BlackLab` so it calls the super class of `Dog` (hence `Animal.equals()`) and not the super class of `BlackLab` (which would be `Dog`).

Think of it like this: If you don't override a `equals` (or any other method for that matter) it implicitly is defined as:

```
class BlackLab extends Dog {
  ...
  boolean equals( Object o ) {
    return super.equals( o );
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: If this is true, then I don't know why this is happening. When I debug through the code with eclipse I can watch it jumping from `super.equals(obj)` to the same method it's already inside of. And I did try implementing a .equals that just returns super.equals in the BlackLab, but it still did the same thing.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it basically explains that the situation I described could not be true, and that I was misdescribing the actual behavior of super.x

Answer (score 4):

**Edit after your edit:**

The short of it is, yes, just don't call `super.equals` at all. Also, make sure that `super.equals` checks its incoming object's class using class equality, not `instanceof`. That's what `Object.equals` does by default, so if `Animal` hasn't declared an `equals`, you're good.

The rest of my answer is still relevant, though, because the above is basically a summary of the conclusion in the last paragraph as it was before. Basically, if the superclass doesn't need to be equal to instances of the subclass, then everyone can just check for object equality (not `instanceof`) and whatever state they want. If the superclass only checks for `instanceof` (not the stricter equality), then basically subclasses can't check any extra state other than what the super class checks.

In your case, an Animal doesn't check anything, and a Dog does. So you're good to go.

Original answer below:

---

Are you thinking that two BlackLabs are equal if (a) they're equal by some specific BlackLab qualities and (b) they're equal by Dogness? If so, this is a bad idea! It breaks the transitive property of equality specified by [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Imagine you had:

- BlackLab a
- BlackLab b
- Dog c

Let's say all three are equal by "dogness", such as their weight, height and name. But the two BlackLabs aren't equal by BlackLabness, such as the sheen of their coat. Now you have:

- a = c
- b = c
- a != b // breaks transitivity!

If on the other hand, `BlackLab.equals` does not add any extra checks -- then you don't need to override it at all. It'll just inherit the equality from Dog, which is what you want.

As Mattias Buelens points out, you can solve this problem by being more strict about your type checking -- requiring both objects to be of the same exact class, rather than using `instanceof`. This fixes the equality contract, but at the cost a BlackLab "Rex" who weighs 80lbs not being equal to a dog of unspecified breed named "Rex" who weighs 80lbs. If you think about the specific use cases you need, you may well discover that that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Note that you can preserve transitivity by adding a `this.getClass() == obj.getClass()` check.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe my example was a little bad. Let me try to fix it ... I fixed it to explain that the reasoning for this has to do with the fact that the Dog class has a generic in it.

Comment: I actually do have some stuff in Animal that is relevant. I removed the call to super.equals and added those checks using the getters. So I have it working now, although I really don't like it much. If I change the behavior of Animal and its equals method, I shouldn't need to modify the same stuff in its decendant classes, that's the point of inheritance! And they did already use class equality, rather than instanceof. (Although I also recently learned that for the Hibernate entities I have to use instanceof ... grrr)

Comment: I suppose I could make a helper protected method in Animal like `animalFieldsAreEqual` that the animal equal method calls and Dog does too in its equals ... I don't like that much either though.

Comment: You could do a hybrid, where `equals` takes care of the boilerplate and calls `animalFieldsAreEqual`, which can use inheritance in the usual super-y ways. Like this: https://gist.github.com/yshavit/212ea023e549e833d250